# Addition of UINavigationBar has changed the background color of UITabBar

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios10, uitabbar

So I'm building a tabbed application and the design calls for a UINavigationBar on some of the app's pages.   After adding the navigation bar to one of my tabbed ViewControllers, the color of the UITabBar changed from the color that it has been set to originally (bluish-green) to grey.  I've tried setting the TabBar Background color in my AppDelegate (which works fine on all other tabs), I've tried setting it locally in the custom TabBar View Controller (does not affect the color at all), I even tried setting it in the specific View Controller itself. I've tried setting a runtim property as well to no avail. I'm at a loss of what to try next.  I've posted the code and screen shots below.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Firebase
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let myGreenBG = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 43/255.0, green: 111/255.0, blue: 109/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = myGreenBG

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = myGreenBG


    return true

}
...
```

TabBarViewController.swift
    import UIKit

```
class tabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myGreenBG = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 43/255.0, green: 111/255.0, blue: 109/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    //self.tabBar.delegate = self

    //Code to render the unselected images in the tab bar
    tabBar.backgroundColor = myGreenBG
    for items in 0 ..< tabBar.items!.count {
        let tabItemIndex = tabBar.items![items]
        tabItemIndex.image = tabItemIndex.image!.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        /*for tabBarItem in (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items!)!{
            if !(tabBarItem.
            }
        }*/
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
    ...
```

Correctly displayed
[image: correct]

Incorrectly displayed
[image: Incorrect]

Any Advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 43/255.0, green: 111/255.0, blue: 109/255.0, alpha: 1.0)  try this in viewWillApear and in ViewWillDisappear reset to its previous color

Comment: @JaydeepVyas unfortunately that did not work.  It seems that setting it as a background color means its there but below whatever the NavBar settings add.   It seems setting barTintColor, as Abhishek suggested, is the only way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to change UITabBar background color-

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this does reset the color, though in my previous example, using the backgroundColor attribute caused it to be much lighter than the shade that appears using barTintColor.  Regardless, I can work with this solution, so thank you!